# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una consulta seleccionando lo que quiero ver en la vista de la app en vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, vue.js

Este es el diálogo que despliega el botón para seleccionar el mesero y el día.
Tengo mi consulta en el archivo *orden.js*, ya verificada en mysql de que es funcional, pero no encuentro la manera de poder hacer lo que necesito.

De nuevo, mi objetivo es poder mostrar en una vista la información del `SELECT`.

```
<v-dialog v-model="nl_dialog" max-width="500px">
    <v-card>
        <v-card-title>Consulta por mesero y fecha</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
            <v-container>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col cols='6'>
                        <v-select
                            :items="meseros"
                            v-model="buscar_orden.ord_mesero_id"
                            label='Mesero'
                        >
                        </v-select>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols='6'>
                        <v-menu
                            v-model="menu1"
                            :close-on-content-click="false"
                            :nudge-right="40"
                            transition="scale-transition"
                            offset-y
                            min-width="auto"
                        >
                            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                <v-text-field
                                    v-model="buscar_orden.ord_fecha_dia"
                                    label="Fecha"
                                    prepend-icon="far fa-calendar-alt"
                                    readonly
                                    v-bind="attrs"
                                    v-on="on"
                                ></v-text-field>
                            </template>
                            <v-date-picker
                            v-model="buscar_orden.ord_fecha_dia"
                            @input="menu1 = false"
                            ></v-date-picker>
                        </v-menu>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color='success' @click="buscar_mf(ord_mesero_id, ord_fecha_dia)"> Buscar</v-btn>
            <v-btn color='error' @click="cancelar()"> Cancelar</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Comment: este es la consulta de orden.js:

'SELECT * '+
                    'FROM mesero  AS m '+ 
                    'INNER JOIN orden AS o '+ 
                        'ON m.mesero_id = o.ord_mesero_id '+
                    'WHERE o.ord_fecha_dia = ? AND o.ord_mesero_id = ? '+
                    'GROUP BY m.mesero_id '+
                    'ORDER BY m.mesero_id ASC ';

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que mencionas en tu comentario.

Comment: Por favor retroalimenta tu pregunta con más información, ejemplos, códigos de prueba, resultados obtenidos, etcétera. Todo para que tengas más oportunidades de que alguien colabore a ayudarte y a resolver tu problema. Te invito a que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)